# Angular CLI multiple dynamic components load to parent component

Tags: angular, dynamic, angular-cli, frontend

I'm developing angular application with dynamic views. So users can customize the view of their choice (what to view/not). Customize part can be done easily but data view part is kind a difficult with angular (or i cannot figure it out). I want to load multiple dynamic components with their data loaded (ex-if their select tag inside that dynamic component i want to load it's option data and add that component to my main component). Another thing is i want to check which dynamic components want to load to main component. Is it possible? Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for:

- conditional importing - Here's a webpack plugin for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-conditional-loader
- dynamic import -
  https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/webpack-and-dynamic-imports-doing-it-right-72549ff49234

  ```
  export default function pageLoader(platform) {
     switch (platform="desktop") {
       case "mobile":
         return import("components/MyMobileComponent");

       case "desktop":
         return import("components/MyDesktopComponent");
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how to append it to the view?

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this Help:

app.component.ts :

```
import { Component, NgModule, Compiler } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor(private compiler: Compiler,
              private router: Router) {}

  createDynamic() {
    const template = '<span>generated on the fly</span>';
    const tmpCmp = Component({template: template})(class {});

    const routes = [{path: '', component: tmpCmp}];
    const tmpModule = NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      declarations: [tmpCmp]})(class {});

    this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(tmpModule).then((module) => {

      const appRoutes = [...this.router.config];

      const route = {
        path: 'dynamic',
        loadChildren() { return module }
      };

      appRoutes.push(route);

      this.router.resetConfig(appRoutes);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/dynamic');
    });
  }
}
```

app.component.html :

```
<p>
  Dynamic Routes
</p>


<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<button (click)="createDynamic()">Go Dynamic</button>
```

load component dynamically, [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-routes-angular-example?file=src%2Fstyles.css)